# Как увидеть данные отправленные через jQuery ajax функцию?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть jQuery ajax функция

```
      $.ajax({
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "/home/profile/edit",
        data: profile.currentField,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log('success');
        },
        error: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
  })
}
```

Как  увидеть отправленные данные  ?

Посмотрел  google chrome  `console.log(data)` который между прочим *при статусе 200* возвращается из *ajax callback*  функции **error**, нечего похожего на отправленные данные не нашел.

Comment: Отправленные данные от сервера или от клиента данные вас интересуют?

Comment: Отправленные данные  клиента

Answer (score 2):

Вы выводите данные присланные сервером при возникновении ошибки. Чтоб посмотреть данные отправляемые клиентом напишите `console.log(profile.currentField)` перед ajax запросом. Так же как вариант через консоль разработчика во вкладке network выбрать интересующий вас запрос.